# Identify where value changes from "A" to "B" for a group [R]

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a table, `data`, that looks like this:

```
data <- data.frame(
  group_id = c(1234, 4567, 4567, 1234, 1710, 1710, 1710),
  value = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A")
)
```

I want to identify how many in `group_id` had a `value` change from 'A' to 'B.' In some cases, there may be multiple value changes, such as 1710, where 'A' -> 'B' -> 'A'.

Ideally, I would capture those changes too, but mostly I am interested in the change from 'A' to 'B'.

I have tried the below, which can tell me the total number of changes, but not for what I am interested in understanding.

```
data %>%
  arrange(desc(created_date)) %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>% 
  summarise(changes = sum(value != lag(value), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Maybe `sum(value == 'A' & lag(value, default = "A") != 'A')`

Comment: What is your expected output for the given sample? Also, make sure your code is reproducible. You reference the column `created_date` but this is not included in the sample. Is this important or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my comment to the question as an answer.

I have commented out `arrange` because column `created_date` is not in the data example.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

count_changes <- function(x, base = 'A') {
  sum(x == base & dplyr::lag(x, default = base) != base, na.rm = TRUE)
}

data %>%
  # arrange(desc(created_date)) %>%
  group_by(group_id) %>% 
  summarise(changes = count_changes(value))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   group_id changes
#>      <dbl>   <int>
#> 1     1234       0
#> 2     1710       1
#> 3     4567       0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>